# Postgresql constraint

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I cannot seem to get this right, I am trying to modify a field to be a foreign key, with cascading delete... what am i doing wrong?

```
ALTER TABLE my_table 
ADD CONSTRAINT $4 
FOREIGN KEY my_field 
REFERENCES my_foreign_table 
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It would help if you posted the error message. But I think you are just missing the parenthesis:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table 
ADD CONSTRAINT my_fk 
FOREIGN KEY (my_field) 
REFERENCES my_foreign_table 
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: @Stephane See the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141266/postgresql-foreign-key-on-delete-cascade) "_A foreign key with a cascade delete means that if a record in the parent table is deleted, then the corresponding records in the child table with automatically be deleted. This is called a cascade delete._" Seems like something you wouldn't want to automatically include unless you wanted to bind the tables together instead of just creating a reference.

Comment: @RichardD, when You don't include it, You must use CASCADE keyword with query, and You remember of consequences then :)

Comment: @Line it can be very useful for the delete to cascade automatically if the data with the foreign key doesn't make sense without the data it is referencing. Then there would be no point in saving it after deleting the referenced data anyway.

Comment: If you need to reference a column in a table, use `REFERENCES my_foreign_table(my_foreign_column)`.

Answer (score 13):

Just guessing: shouldn't you add a foreign key instead of a constraint?

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD FOREIGN KEY (my_field) REFERENCES my_foreign_table;
```

[Postgresql reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/ddl-alter.html)

Answer (score 13):

I'm still somehow missing here an answer with foreign column (`foreign_field`) explicitly specified:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD CONSTRAINT my_fk
FOREIGN KEY (my_field)
REFERENCES my_foreign_table (foreign_field)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 2):

This works to me, I add the column to the table and then add the constraint with references to the other table:

```
-- add column to table 
ALTER TABLE schema.table ADD COLUMN my_column type;  

-- add constraint to column 
ALTER TABLE schema.table ADD CONSTRAINT fk_name FOREIGN KEY (column)
REFERENCES schema.table (column) MATCH SIMPLE 
ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```