# How to create one table which shares common id with another and which row gets removed in both tables once it's removed from first

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, cascade, database-administration

How to create one table which shares common id with another and which row gets removed in both tables once it's removed from first?

I heard about FOREIGN KEY, REFERENCES but not sure how to actually create such tables.
Any example to get me started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're either talking about a cascading delete or something really weird that you shouldn't do. :)

Info on foreign keys: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-fk.html

Info on cascading deletes (search the page for "ON DELETE CASCADE"): http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ddl-constraints.html

**Edit:** adding example:

Table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    product_no integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    price numeric
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    shipping_address text,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE order_items (
    product_no integer REFERENCES products ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    order_id integer REFERENCES orders ON DELETE CASCADE,
    quantity integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_no, order_id)
);
```

Example of triggering cascading delete:

```
DELETE FROM orders                  -- This will delete all orders with 
WHERE order_id BETWEEN 1 AND 10 ;   -- order_id between 1 and 10 and 
                                    -- all associated order items.
```

Comment: Well, I read that already. Can you show working example, you right first

Comment: An example of what? Creating a set of tables that utilize a cascading delete?

Comment: @Jason: The answer is fine, except for the last part. Deleting from `order_items` will not cascade anything. If you delete any row from the `orders` though, then yes, all associated rows in `order_items` will be deleted (through the cascade effect), too

Comment: Ok got it, I was deleting order_items and expected that orders'd be modified instead of vice-verse :/

Comment: Whoops, that's what I meant to do. Thanks for the correction.