# When an employee is deleted delete referenced rows in Works_On and Dependent

Tags: postgresql

```
ALTER TABLE WORKS_ON ADD constraint 
companyFK3 FOREIGN KEY(Essn) 
REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (Ssn);


ALTER TABLE WORKS_ON  ADD constraint 
companyFK4 FOREIGN KEY(Pno)
REFERENCES PROJECT (Pnumber);
```

The problem is i don't know how to add CASCADE DELETE FOR  it 
.

Link to  DB:https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xhEj2sAgdTMABBkCtJvmoC/0#&togetherjs=z3CKywAccH

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL: FOREIGN KEY/ON DELETE CASCADE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141266/postgresql-foreign-key-on-delete-cascade)

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE WORKS_ON ADD constraint 
companyFK3 FOREIGN KEY(Essn) 
REFERENCES EMPLOYEE (Ssn) ON DELETE CASCADE;


ALTER TABLE WORKS_ON  ADD constraint 
companyFK4 FOREIGN KEY(Pno)
REFERENCES PROJECT (Pnumber) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: almost, i thought its [`DELETE CASCADE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14141354/4648586) no?

Comment: Of course it makes sense and is absolutely neccessary to explainyour answer. And if the other question is a duplicate, mark it as a duplicate!